# opengl glReadPixels

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to get color of a pixel. The pixel is mouse position. I use `glReadPixels` but i can't

```
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    unsigned char pixel[3];
    glReadPixels(pt.x, pt.y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
```

After this codes value of pixel is: `'Ì'`
any idea?

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: So you printed the pixel to the console... hm?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to store the rgb color of a position(for example 50*50) in the pixel array. I saw the value of pixel array in a breakpoint in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Is your problem that Visual Studio is showing an `unsigned char` value as a *character*? Because it's going to do that.

Comment: I want to rgb color of my mouse position in PIXEL array. for example by moving my mouse the value of `pixels[0][0][0]` must be changed(0 to 255) but it is always 204. And my mouse moving doesn't changes this value

Comment: this is always true: `if(pixels[0][0][0] == 204)` and moving mouse doesn't change this

Comment: @user1972067 The value of `pixel[0][0][0]`? Huh, is this part of a larger array and you didn't show us the real code? Or did you miswrite those comments? Or are you really trying to use `[0][0][0]` on an `unsigned char[3]` (though that should rather be a compiler error)?

Comment: excuse me. I mean `pixel[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`204` is `CC` in hex representation. This value is often used to fill non-initialized memory. If you'll initialize `pixel` with zero (for example)

```
 unsigned char pixel[3] = {0};
```

99,(9)% you'll see zero after call to `glReadPixels`. Depending on [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) `glReadPixels`

> If an error is generated, no change is made to the contents of data.

that is your data in `pixel` was not changed because of error. Follow @OlegTitov's fourth advice (look for what `glGetError();` will tell you)

**Upd:** If you want to get a pixel value from the main screen using only `glReadPixels`, and if you didn't create any GLFrameBuffer, I'm not sure, but I think you'll fail. I'll repeat - I'm not sure, but I think, that `glReadPixels` can read pixel values only from frame buffers, that was previously created by gl-functions

Comment: Thanks. you are right about `unsigned char pixel[3] = {0};`. But i cant understand how to fix this problem? `glGetError();` returns error 1282 invalid operation. What does it means?

Comment: Here - http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml - is description of all errors, that can `glGetError()` produce. Look for value of each constant from there and you'll get an answer

Answer (score 2):

1. When outputting `char` to console, compiler will print as a symbol, not as letter. This is done for C style strings could be printed normal way. To print integer value first cast variable to integer type.
2. When reading from screen: Note that openGL's coordinate origin is bottom left corner while window systems use upper left corner, so you need to convert from one coordinate system to another

   glReadPixels(pt.x, window_height - pt.y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
3. If you experience further problems make sure that correct pixel buffer is bound as read beffer. For window output:

   glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
4. If still have some problems start checking your code with `glGetError();`